# Unable to call my Formparam webservice and getting HTTP 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, weblogic

I wrote a FormParam webservice and able to publish the webservice and getting the HTTP 404 error in calling the respective HTML.

Here are my Webservice, HTML and Web.xml code.

WebService:

```
  @Path("/UserService")
    public class UserWS {
    @POST
       @Path("add")
       @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
       public String addUserInfo(@FormParam("name") String name,
                                 @FormParam("age") int age )
       {
           return "You sent me two userids using Form param annotation ----> " + name                                       + " and " + age;
       }
   }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Sending Form Parameters to Restful Web service (JAX-RS)</h1>
    <form action = http://localhost:7001/UserWS/rest/UserService/add" method="post">
        <p>
            User's Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            User's Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add User info" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>UserWS</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UserWS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>learning.webservice.users</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UserWS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am using the Eclipse IDE and Weblogic Server for my webservice Development and deployement respectively.

I am able to call the other calling params like, PathParam, Query Param, Matrix Param from the same place. This causing the problem only in passing the FormParam case. I am able to use FormDataParam too from the same webservice (UserWS).
Could you help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Your action quotes in html doesn't close properly.

Comment: Thanq, I haven't noticed that and spent almost a day in tracking down the issue. Now it is working fine.